# Don't copy files that cause an input/output error

Tags: rsync, scp, file-transfer, cp

When copying files from a faulty hd with cp, rsync, or scp, the faulty files which can't be read anymore are also partly copied to the destination directory.

Is there an option to automatically skip or delete files on the destination drive causing an input/output error while copying?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27637277 for `--ignore-missing-args` option.

Answer (score 3):

`rsync`  has options `--delete` and `--ignore-errors` that together might have the outcome you want.